# How to automatically add bookmarks to Google Chrome?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, bookmarks

I have a text file that has a lot of bookmarks in text form. It looks something like this

```
$ cat bookmarks
www.google.com
www.stackoverflow.com
www.superuser.com
www.unix.stackexchange.com
$
```

- I want all these bookmarks to be saved in my Chrome browser. How can I do it without having to open each page in the browser and adding it as a bookmark manually?

  I tried importing this text file from the Import Bookmarks option, but it doesn't work.

  Is there some good way of doing this?
- Also, it would be awesome if I can update the bookmarks for example by adding the url at the end of the **bookmarks** file and then resyncing.
- I am using Chrome on Ubuntu, so any Linux tricks/hacks for doing this are also fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use Chrome, but since you feel comfortable with Linux tricks/hacks, why don't you:

1. Export bookmarks from Chrome's Bookmarks Manager
2. Study the format of the file and its entries
3. Transform your text file into this format
4. Import the file

I would suggest making first a try with importing one bookmark address using a hand-crafted file, just to validate the concept.

Comment: Can confirm that this (still) works today. All you have to do is export the bookmarks, edit the resulting html file so it only contains the *new* bookmarks you want to add, and import it back. The new bookmarks will then show up in a folder called "Imported" in the Bookmarks Manager, which you can then freely move wherever.

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome for Linux stores bookmarks in JSON file located in ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks. You probably can transform your line-by-line list to JSON format using linux shell commands. I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: An important note, here, is that you cannot have Chrome running while updating the bookmarks file; it will revert.  And at least in my Gnome, I had to go to some lengths to make sure Chrome was truly, completely closed.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use [Xmarks](http://xmarks.com) web interface to add bookmarks programmatically.